# gradient vector exercise with maximum value

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the points $(x,y)$ and directions for which the directional derivative of $f (x, y) = 3x ^{2} + y ^{2}$ has the maximum value, if $(x,y)$ is in the circle $x ^{2} + y ^{2} = 1$.

I know that if $f (x, y) = 3x ^{2} + y ^{2}$ and $g(x,y) = x ^{2} + y ^{2}$, then by Lagrange multipliers method, exist $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f(x _{0}, y _{0}) = \lambda \nabla g(x _{0}, y _{0})$. I know that
$$ \nabla f(x _{0}, y _{0}) = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x _{0}, y _{0}), \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x _{0}, y _{0})  \right) = (6x, 2y)$$
and
$$ \nabla g(x _{0}, y _{0}) = \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x _{0}, y _{0}), \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x _{0}, y _{0})  \right) = (2x, 2y), $$
then $6x = 2\lambda x$ and $2x = 2\lambda x$, but I do not know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure that you’re solving the correct problem? Lagrange multipliers will let you maximize $f$, but the way you’ve worded the question, you’re asking about maximizing the _directional derivative_ (in which direction?) of $f$, not the _value_ of $f$.

Comment: I want maximizing the directional derivative, but I do not know how I can do it, I thought it was this way, but if you know how you do this exercise, please, you tell me a suggestion :)

Comment: What do you mean by “directional derivative” here? A directional derivative requires a direction, but there no mention of one. Do you perhaps mean the norm of $\nabla f$?

Comment: yes, I know that $f´(x;y) = \Vert \nabla f(x) \Vert $ if  $f$ in the point $(x,y)$ reaches its maximum

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the function $$f(x^2,1-x^2)=3x^2+1-x^2$$

Comment: and do the same for the function $g$?

Comment: I would make it so

Comment: thanks for help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here $6x_0 = 2\lambda x_0$ and $2y_0 = 2\lambda y_0$. You can choose the values of the above variables to get either a minimum or a maximum. For a maximum $y_0=0$, $x_0=1$ and $\lambda = 3$. You can see by inspection the maximum would be when we have maximum $x^2$ and minimum $y^2$ for their sum equalling $1$.